# VBA - Transfer a Range of a sheet to a function

Tags: vba, excel

I can't manage to transfer the full name of a Range to a function.

I have 2 sheets : WS1 and WS2.

In a Sub, I find various ranges related to WS1 and WS2.
But when I debug, their coordinates are not preceded by the name of the sheet:

```
Public Function myFunction(ByRef amountRange As Range)
....
End Function






Sub Testons()
'
Dim nb As Integer, lastrow As Integer,
Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS1 = .Worksheets("WS1"): Set WS2 = .Worksheets("WS2")
    End With

    With Worksheets("WS1")
        nb = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        lastrow = nb + 1
        Set amountRange = WS1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
'THIS RESULTS IN 'WS1'!$C$2:$C$9 AND NOT IN 'WS1'!$C$2:$C$9 (what I want)
    End With
    result = myFunction(amountRange)
End Sub
```

Consequently, my function can't do what I want.
How to have a Range preceded by the worksheet name eg 'WS1'!$C$2:$C$9 ?

Comment: Why do you need it to? You are not passing the address?

Comment: Not clear what you're after.  `'THIS RESULTS IN 'WS1'!$C$2:$C$9 AND NOT IN 'WS1'!$C$2:$C$9 (what I want)` - they're both the same result.  `Dim nb As Integer, lastrow As Integer` - these will cause overflow errors, change them to `long`.  `AmountRange` holds a reference to `C2:Cxxxx` on the WS1 sheet.  To get the exact **string** you're after use `"'" & amountrange.Parent.name & "'!" & amountrange.Address`

Comment: I assume in `Testons()` you're declaring `amountRange` as a Range? You're passing the Range itself to myFunction, so you need to look at what you're doing with it there.

Answer (score 1):

This is because VBA handles references to cells in another way than excel does.

you can find the coordinates of the range with

> range.address

and the sheet where the cells belongs to with

> range.parent.name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Darren 
`"'" & amountrange.Parent.name & "'!" & amountrange.Address` is the answer I needed.
I'm using now :

```
amountRange.Address(External:=True)
```